# Replace certain arabic words in text string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic-support

I have a text string in arabic and i want to make some words Bold and add icons before the word

the method I am using for this for english text is

```
var wordsToBold = ["Properties", "How To Use"];

    function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
        return input.replace(new RegExp('(\\b)(' + wordsToBold.join('|') + ')(\\b)', 'ig'),
            '<br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i>$1<b>$2</b>$3');
    }
```

When i use this method with arabic words it does not working

```
var wordsToBold = ["الخصائص", "طريقة الاستعمال"];
```

A text for testing:

> فرانكوا اراب الخصائص: لوريم ايبسوم دولار سيت أميت ,كونسيكتيتور أدايبا
> يسكينج أليايت,سيت دو أيوسمود تيمبور
>
> أنكايديديونتيوت لابوري ات دولار ماجنا أليكيوا . طريقة الاستعمال: وت
> انيم أد مينيم فينايم,كيواس نوستريد
>
> أكسير سيتاشن يللأمكو لابورأس

Comment: Does it output any error?

Comment: @Masood No, the regular expression does not recognize the words in array at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your own Unicode word boundaries:

1. Left-hand (leading) word boundary pattern can be defined as a position that is not immediately preceded with letter + any potential diacritics or a digit or an underscore: `(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])`
2. Right-hand (trailing) word boundary pattern can be defined as a position that is not immediately followed with a letter, digit or  underscore: `(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])`.

Thus, you can use

```js
var wordsToBold = ["Properties", "How To Use"];

function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(?<!\\p{L}\\p{M}*|[\\p{N}_])(?:' + wordsToBold.join('|') + ')(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}_])', 'igu'),
        '<br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i><b>$&</b>');
}
console.log(makeBold("How To Use These Properties: 00How To Use These Properties00", wordsToBold));
// => <br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i><b>How To Use</b> These <br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i><b>Properties</b>: 00How To Use These Properties00
var wordsToBold = ["الخصائص", "طريقة الاستعمال"];
var arString = `فرانكوا اراب الخصائص: لوريم ايبسوم دولار سيت أميت ,كونسيكتيتور أدايبا يسكينج أليايت,سيت دو أيوسمود تيمبور

أنكايديديونتيوت لابوري ات دولار ماجنا أليكيوا . طريقة الاستعمال: وت انيم أد مينيم فينايم,كيواس نوستريد

أكسير سيتاشن يللأمكو لابورأس`;
console.log(makeBold(arString, wordsToBold));
// => فرانكوا اراب <br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i><b>الخصائص</b>: لوريم ايبسوم دولار سيت أميت ,كونسيكتيتور أدايبا يسكينج أليايت,سيت دو أيوسمود تيمبور أنكايديديونتيوت لابوري ات دولار ماجنا أليكيوا . <br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i><b>طريقة الاستعمال</b>: وت انيم أد مينيم فينايم,كيواس نوستريد أكسير سيتاشن يللأمكو لابورأس
```

If you want a more generic Unicode-aware `\b`, you should keep in mind [what a Unicode-aware `\w` actually matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772689/3832970) (`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`), and keeping in mind that `\b` can be written as `(?:(?<=^)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=$)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W))`, you can use the following:

```js
const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=$)|(?<=${nw})(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}))`;
console.log(uwb);
```

The `makeBold` function will look like

```js
const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=$)|(?<=${nw})(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}))`;

function makeBold(input, wordsToBold) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp(`${uwb}(?:${wordsToBold.join('|')})${uwb}`, 'gu'),
        '<br><br><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-xs mr-2"></i><b>$&</b>');
}

// Test
var wordsToBold = ["الخصائص", "طريقة الاستعمال"];
var arString = `فرانكوا اراب الخصائص: لوريم ايبسوم دولار سيت أميت ,كونسيكتيتور أدايبا يسكينج أليايت,سيت دو أيوسمود تيمبور     أنكايديديونتيوت لابوري ات دولار ماجنا أليكيوا . طريقة الاستعمال: وت انيم أد مينيم فينايم,كيواس نوستريد     أكسير سيتاشن يللأمكو لابورأس`;
console.log(makeBold(arString, wordsToBold));
```

**Please bear in mind the `u` flag** that makes it possible to use Unicode category classes inside the ECMAScript 2018+ compliant `RegExp` patterns.

Comment: (I can not believe you got a downvote for this man ++) I have question out of curiosity, why does the lefthand word boundary have `\p{M}` and the right hand not?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Because diacritics are not used on their own, they are always part of a *base* character, which is usually a letter, but - probably - can be a digit, too. I have only seen diacritics after letters so far.

Comment: Aha, makes sense now, thanks! I'll bookmark it.

Comment: What exactly is more generic about the second solution compared to the first one?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It is actually a Unicode word boundary equivalent of `\b`.

Comment: Whereas the first solution is something else?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Of course, otherwise, I'd say "here is an absolutely synonymic solution". `(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])` is a left-hand word boundary Unicode work-around and the `(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])` is a right-hand word boundary Unicode work-around. Here, "work-around" means this word boundary is "generalized" (or "primitivized") since the Unicode category classes (and also `_`, which is part of `\p{Pc}`) are not as specific as the real Unicode word boundary would check. If the first solution (work-around) is good enough, it is fine not to use the long real Unicode word boundary equivalent.

Comment: What false positives or false negatives may I get with the work-around?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Other than asking theoretic questions (that you can easily answer at the https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm site), could you explain what your real issue is?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to know whether it is safe to fall back onto your first solution if your second one proves to be too slow for some real inputs in my case (which I am yet to test).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning If your main pattern matches word characters on both ends, and you are mainly working with non-"heavily" diacritic languages, then the first solution is good enough. If you plan to work with languages like Tamil, Hebrew, where `\p{Mc}` does not match all the diacritic characters in the language, you will have to make sure the generic `\p{M}` is used. You need to understand here that word boundary is a very specific construct and it is crucial to check your main pattern first, then adjust the word boundary pattern based on the potential inputs.

Comment: Yes, one of the languages I target is Hebrew. In your estimate, how much slower is the generic pattern than the built-in `\b` for ASCII? In other words, how much slower will I process Hebrew text compared to a text in English?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning In that case, and *granted the strings are all (Unicode) word characters*, I think you can use the first solution here (maybe replace `[\\p{N}_]` with `[\\p{N}\\p{Pc}]` to be on the safer side) and it should work fine. In case your main patterns can start/end with punctuation, that will require a different approach.