# Replace any words in a phrase using Regex in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have to remove words in a phrase (anywhere in it) and have this so far:

```
replace(/^(dog|cat) */, '');
```

This is working only if 'dog' or 'cat' are in the beginning of a phrase, but does not do the job if it is somewhere else. I see that the question is in this ^ symbol, but I am lacking knowledge to construct a complete query.

EDIT: The thing I need is something like this to work for other words in a string as well (including Cyrillic):

```
replace(/\s*\b(?:DOG|dog|СОБАКА|собака)\b/g, '');
```

Comment: Use word boundaries, `replace(/\s*\b(?:dog|cat)\b/g, '');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How would you solve the issue of text like `cat sentence here.`? The regex removes leading whitespace only so you're left with a space before "sentence".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nevermind, I think I got it https://regex101.com/r/Yaorgi/1/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `.trim()` will do.

Comment: See how to build a [Unicode-aware word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680139/replace-certain-arabic-words-in-text-string-using-javascript/66680311#66680311) here.

Comment: I am trying to find it there, but no luck so far without the Regex knowledge :( The thing I need is something like this to work for other words in a string as well:
replace(/\s*\b(?:DOG|dog|СОБАКА|собака)\b/g, '');