# Having difficulty matching entire sentence containing certain words, if the word of interest is the first of the sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

Utilizing REGEX pattern:

```
[^?!.\s][^?!.]*?\b([Cc]at|[Dd]og|[Bb]ird)\b[^?!.]*[.?!]
```

to match an entire sentence with the above-included words, even if the sentence spans multiple lines.

However, I've found that if the word of interest is the first in the sentence, it will not match.

For example:
The bird is dead. Will Match.
Dog days are over. Will Not.
Often the sentences I'm looking for are incomplete grammatically as the second listed, but follow a beginning capitalization and followed by period structure.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Note there can also be a way with a lookahead, but it will probably require a more resource consuming pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?=\s)[^?!.]*?\b([Cc]at|[Dd]og|[Bb]ird)\b[^?!.]*[.?!]
\b[^?!.]*?\b([Cc]at|[Dd]og|[Bb]ird)\b[^?!.]*[.?!]
```

In the first regex, the first matched char MUST be a non-whitespace char because the `(?=\s)` is a *positive lookahead* that matches a location that is immediately followed with a whitespace char.

The `\b` in the second variant is more specific and matches a position between a start of string/non-word char and a word char, or between a word char and a non-word char/end of string.

Note that in JavaScript `\b` word boundary is not Unicode-aware, and if you need full Unicode word boundary support, you will need a workaround, see [Replace certain arabic words in text string using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66680311/3832970).